# Unable to filter JSON output using jq. I am using CURL

Tags: json, key, jq

I am unable to filter the following.

I need to find out the count of names starting with "SnapshotSet" which are under the name tag of the below JSON file.

Example - `"name": "SnapshotSet.1475076959480"`

As a first step I am trying to filter out all the names starting with SnapshotSet...but receiving the following error.

jq `'.snapshot-sets[]' testjq`
error: sets is not defined

But when I filter out links I am able to get an output

```
  jq '.links[]' testjq
{
  "href": "https://test.com/api/json/v2/types/snapshot-sets/",
  "rel": "self"
}
```

Anything to do with the name "snapshot-sets"?

Please find the JSON file below.

```
{
"links": [
    {
        "href": "https://test.com/api/json/v2/types/snapshot-sets/",
        "rel": "self"
    }
],
"snapshot-sets": [
    {
        "href": "https://test.com/api/json/v2/types/snapshot-sets/1",
        "name": "SnapshotSet.1475076959480"
    },
    {
        "href": "https://test.com/api/json/v2/types/snapshot-sets/3",
        "name": "SnapshotSet.1475165496304"
    },
    {
        "href": "https://test.com/api/json/v2/types/snapshot-sets/2",
        "name": "SnapshotSet.1475158265437"
    },
    {
        "href": "https://test.com/api/json/v2/types/snapshot-sets/63659",
        "name": "server1a_b_c_STFS1474869600618"
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/940), the abbreviated form `.keyname` cannot be used when the key contains the `-` character.

You can run the following to get the list of all names from your file:

```
jq '."snapshot-sets"[].name' testjq
```